# How to read an empty array in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my ADF pipeline, I am trying to capture one comma separated column value and pass it as an array type parameter to another pipeline.

Problem arises when the source column has no data. The ADF variable takes "" as array element and returns the array as [""] instead of [] as an empty array.

How can I get [] as empty array when the column returns blank?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `No quote character` in Dataset properties.

[image]

The single character to quote column values if it contains column delimiter.
The default value is **double quotes** ".

When quoteChar is defined as empty string, it means there is no quote char and column value is not quoted, and escapeChar is used to escape the column delimiter and itself.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#dataset-properties